# LibGdx collision detection between sprites?

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, collision-detection

Using `accelerometer` my sprite image is moving left and right and if I touch my screen the sprite is moving to Y-axis.I want to make a collision detection between different sprites so that if the sprite pass through an object it will stop to hide in that object. I already watch a tutorial this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1aN--vTqLc but nothings happen. What is the proper way to make collition detection? I don't know what's wrong with my coding.Any suggestion or much better tutorial Thank's and Advance

Here is my coding

```
private Rectangle rectangleCat;
private Rectangle rectangleShoes;
private float yPosition = -40;
```

Sprite

```
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat.png"));
    catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
    catX=300;
    catY=0;

    sprite_shoes = new Sprite(new Texture("equip/Shoes.png"));
    sprite_shoes.setPosition(260,580);

   rectangleShoes=new Rectangle(sprite_shoes.getX(),sprite_shoes.getY(),sprite_shoes.getWidth(),sprite_shoes.getHeight());
   rectangleCat = new Rectangle(catsprite.getX(),catsprite.getY(),catsprite.getWidth(),catsprite.getHeight());
```

Render method

```
    boolean isOverlaping = rectangleCat.overlaps(rectangleShoes);
    if(!isOverlaping) {
        System.out.println("not overlap");
        yPosition = yPosition + (20 * delta);

    }
```

My Sprite image and Object is not overlapping

Full source code http://pastebin.com/Dxfx9f65

Comment: When you say that nothing happens, are you saying that `overlaps` never returns `true`?

Comment: For rectangular object, you need to update your rectangle each time when sprite change its position.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your sprite is not sharp Rectangle it's looks like polygon so you need to detect collision between two polygon.

Still if you want to detect collision between rectangle then get Bounding Rectangle of your sprite in `render()` method.

In render method

```
rectangleShoes=sprite_shoes.getBoundingRectangle();
rectangleCat=catsprite.getBoundingRectangle();

boolean isOverlaping = rectangleCat.overlaps(rectangleShoes);
if(!isOverlaping) {
    System.out.println("not overlap");
    yPosition = yPosition + (20 * delta);

}
```